# Porque minha pergunta foi fechada como duplicata se a duvida é distinta?

Tags: debate, fechamento

Depois de hoje ter feito uma [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249300/d%C3%BAvidas-de-seguran%C3%A7a-usando-hash) no SO-pt, ela foi rapidamente colocada como duplicada por um [moderador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero). Após falar com ele e mostrar um exemplo em como existem diferenças, cheguei mesmo a fazer edição na pergunta e não obtive mais respostas dele.

Já agora se a pergunta é assim tão má porque existe um comentário assim:

> O OP não mencionou que a hash seria para senhas. Existem hashes que
>   não são criptográficas (inclusive o crc32, mencionado na própria
>   postagem), bem como o SipHash, enfim. Acho que fechar essa pergunta,
>   por uma relacionada a senhas, é dizer que a única utilidade de hash é
>   senhas. O que não é, e nem sabemos se isso é o que o OP quer. Acho que
>   se o autor especificar o uso, questão deveria de ser reaberta, se não
>   for para senhas.

E porque já tem 5 votos em algumas 2 horas?

Se realmente for duplicada, gostaria que ele que me dissesse quais são os pontos exatos onde a minha questão é esclarecida na outra pergunta.

Comment: a sinalização basica foi pq 90% da questão está respondida na marca de duplicidade, tanto que o comentario a seguir dele foi "Se só sobrou esta dúvida, deixe só ela."

Comment: Você poderia oferecer uma recompensa também na pergunta mais antiga e marcar o motivo, por exemplo: *"necessito de uma resposta com exemplo de uso"*, mas a ideia do Daniel é excelente também. - PS: não vejo nenhum abuso por parte de ninguém, não deve levar a mal uma atitude que na verdade é saudável para a comunidade, afinal se errou podemos reabrir, eu já comentei muito no Meta todos temos direito de errar, até os moderadores

Comment: @DanielGentil na outra pergunta fala alguma coisa soubre outra opção melhor se existir em vez de usar Hash?

Comment: @DanielGentil na outra pergunta fala alguma coisa soubre defina um hash que será utilizado por todo seu sistema

Comment: @DanielGentil na outra fala-se sobre isso "Além de o `sha1` ser o maior é realmente o mais seguro? E em desempenho vale a pena usa-lo?" mas acho que não diretamente....

Comment: @DanielGentil Pergunto onde está então os 90%

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento até certo ponto concordo... mas ia acrescentar 3 duvidas chegava ao ponto que tirava a ideia da pergunta inicial além de que a 1ºpergunta é sobre passwords, eu questionei sobre o sistema em si...

Comment: @Tmc eu só citei como exemplo adicional, mas ok, pode sim ser uma nova pergunta e seguiria a sugestão do Daniel.

Answer (score 11):

Começando pelo comentário infeliz:

> O OP não mencionou que a hash seria para senhas

Sim, é sobre senhas ou algo análogo a senhas em todo o texto, desde o título, até o final fala o tempo neste uso e não no uso de *hashes* para verificação de conteúdo.

> nem sabemos se isso é o que o OP quer

Se isto fosse verdade deveria fechar como não clara

> Acho que se o autor especificar o uso, questão deveria de ser reaberta, se não for para senhas

Ele confirma que a pergunta deve ser fechada se for sobre o assunto que é, o que o AP não negou que seja ou ajudou esclarecer melhor.

> E porque já tem 5 votos em algumas 2 horas?

Votos e ser duplicata nada tem a ver. Isto já foi discutido várias vezes no meta.

> Se realmente for duplicada, gostaria que ele que me dissesse quais são os pontos exatos onde a minha questão é esclarecida na outra pergunta.

Se tiver paciência até faço isto, muito embora não seja minha obrigação e quase será uma resposta que resume o que está lá na pergunta.

Moderadores são voluntários, não são funcionários da SE, do SOpt e menos ainda de qualquer usuário para exigir que um deles faça o que eles desejam na hora que eles desejam. Moderadores fazem o seu trabalho conforme a disponibilidade e algo que toma tempo precisa esperar.

Enquanto isso pode fazer o mesmo e mostrar porque não é duplicata. Pode mostrar que leu a resposta na pergunta original e mostrar que os pontos na nova pergunta não foram respondidos.

> alguém me consegue dar um exemplo de funcionamento e mais detalhes?

Isto me parece que não foi respondido, ainda que parece ampla para responder. Ou talvez não esteja claro.

As demais questões são sobre a melhor proteção obtida por *hashes* que está na resposta, depois posso pegar pontos específicos.

> Se só sobrou esta dúvida, deixe só ela.

E edição não deixou só esta dúvida. Mesmo que fique só esta, deixo para outros opinarem se daria para responder isto.

## Conclusão

Moderadores podem errar, mas é preciso mostrar onde está o erro. Só reclamar não ajuda em nada.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela atenção, peço desculpa se fui rude